# DynamoDBに登録されている電話番号のLambdaの判定エラーについて

Tags: aws, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

下記の参照エラーですが何かの設定が不足していると思われるのですが、何が不足しているのか調べても分かりません。
よろしくお願いいたします。

エラー内容

```
"errorType": "ReferenceError",
"errorMessage": "require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead",
```

Lambdaコード

```
const AWS = require("aws-sdk");
const DynamoDB = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({ region: "ap-northeast-1" });
const tableName = 'PhoneNumberTable';

exports.handler = async (event) => {
// 発信者番号
const phone = event.Details.ContactData.CustomerEndpoint.Address;
// DynamoDBの一覧取得
const db = await DynamoDB.scan({TableName: tableName}).promise();
// 発信者番号が一覧に存在するかどうかの確認
const result = db.Items.some( item => {
return (item.PhoneNumber == phone);
});
return { result : result };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージから見ると、コードが ES Module として扱われているようなので、require を使う書き方をするなら CommonJS で扱ってもらう必要がありますね。

コードのファイル名が、index.mjs になっているのではないかと思われるので、これを index.js に変えてみてください。

Comment: ありがとうございます。ファイル名を変更いたしましたら下記エラーとなっりました。

Comment: [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'index': No module named 'index'
Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Lambdaファンクションのハンドラー設定はデフォルトの「index.handler」になっていると思います。ここから index というファイル名に関数が用意されていることが求められます。
indexがないということは、ファイル名を変更するときに index.js ではなく、他のファイル名にしてしまっていないでしょうか？